# looking for the way to extract the value of a data-url property from a Li tag in html using "simple_html_dom.php" for scraping

Tags: php

I have a website with this li:

```
<li id="video1" class="streamList Playclick rippler rippler-inverse" data-url="http://54.39.16.47:25461/live/674475857/674475857/461.m3u8">
```

I need to extract the data-url value of it, am using simple_html_dom.php to **scrape** into the page.

have someone work do it with simple_html_dom.php? will be able to help me with an example of how to extract it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this [SimpleHtmlDom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm)?

If yes, try it like in the examples (untested by me)

```php
$html->find('li[id=video1]')->getAttribute('data-url')
```

Comment: Thanks... i found the same solution in another response her at site... but thanks that work perfect.

Comment: Then feel free to link it and / or accept the answer.